# Love-ins? A capital idea for a cryptic crossword

Tags: crosswords

[image]

#### Across

**1** Moves mass across surface of Earth
**3** Carrot top inserted in faithless can for escapades
**6** Empire head removed in revolution
**10** Blurred as at end of day, perhaps start of it
**11** A food riddled with holes. Wherefore? Say, albumen *(2 words)*
**12** Core belief recalled in church aloud
**13** King, perhaps, with unwrapped gift
**16** Sort of music, and the Spanish dance
**18** Channels inside someone's head, and leaves
**21** Perhaps a man in contact with a man, deplorably
**23** Bugs town containing private eye
**24** You got it!
**26** A field encompassing sounds of people
**29** Reverse interment proceedings, generally
**30** Horsepower without horse's home, and music
**31** Washington or St. Petersburg locus
**32** Bell? Sounds abrupt
**33** Pieces together with small tools for an article of clothing

#### Down

**1** Pines without end, for an object of desire
**2** To find the heart of Madras, northward they travel *(2 words)*
**3** Time in a year; part of tree descends in it
**4** Pepper, tomato, garlic heads – evenly distributed in this brand
**5** Like an animal, takes inside, for functional support
**7** "Gangway", for example, or "ship"
**8** Case participant without a name, perhaps
**9** Rome's head of diocese in heart of Carpentras *(2 words)*
**14** Parts, maybe several, working in tandem
**15** Mr. Smith with Mrs. Jones, by way of example
**17** Violently removing pressure, letting it out
**19** Office workers with degrees for confusing issues?
**20** Within half of A.D. 2020, it nearly quadrupled upward
**22** Upper part of earth, possibly mixed up with metal tools
**23** Electrical device with eyes on it *(2 words)*
**25** Audible reactions, for rapid breathing
**27** A word now? No, a source, looking back
**28** Bites, repeatedly, mostly firm stuff
**29** Famous bit in The Sound of Music

---

[Some initial hints are in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54996184#54996184) Another is that

> all the answers are to be written into the white squares allotted to them. None go off of the board or into the black squares. (You might think this obvious, but [some people think more deviously](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54998239#54998239).) The exception of course is 20 Down, which doesn't *have* white squares allotted to it.

Comment: Are the enumerations absent intentionally?

Comment: @hexomino yes but I've just added word counts to make solvers' lives easier

Comment: [some hints are in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54996184#54996184)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick to this puzzle is that

> it's not a cryptic crossword at all! All of these clues are regular crossword clues, phrased to look like cryptic clues.

Additionally,

> every square along the main diagonal of the grid has to have two letters in it. 20-D should be interpreted as going in the center of the grid.

The grid:

> [image]

Clues:

> [image]
>  Some explanation for clues that may be unclear:
>  3D refers to Archie of Archie Comics, a redheaded troublemaker.
>  12A refers to the Christian concept of "remembrance of what God has done".
>  13A refers to the three Magi (wise men) of Biblical fame.
>  18A seems to have a part of speech mismatch: both "channels inside someone's head" and "leaves" are SINUOUS.
>  23A's "Bugs" refers to Bugs Meany, of the Encyclopedia Brown series.
>  30A is (Horsepower without horse)'s home -- the birthplace of the modern automobile. "Motown" is also a musical genre.
>  2D: Madras is directly north of Sri Lanka.
>  4D: CLASSICO is a brand of sauce.
>  7D refers to "ship" in the sense of "romantic pairing".
>  8D: Jane Roe, of Roe vs. Wade fame, was a pseudonym.
>  20D: ZM is the stock ticker symbol for Zoom (the company that develops the teleconferencing program of the same name).
>  23D: "eyes on it" means that people are watching the device, not that the device has eyes physically placed on it.
>  27D: An *etymon* is an obsolete or foreign word that acts as the source for a more modern word.
>  29D refers to the start of Do-Re-Mi, starting "Doe, a deer, a female deer...".
>
>  (Explanation for 20D contributed by Tom.)

Also,

> The bigrams are all two-letter country codes. Taking the first letters of the capitals of those countries (as the title hints) gives LJUBJANA -- if an L is added in the middle, that becomes LJUBLJANA, the capital of Slovenia.
>   [image]
>  (And as pointed out by Peter Shor in the comments, `LOVE-INS? A` is an anagram of `SLOVENIA`!)

Comment: Re "a meaning for the other bigrams", you might consider the rot13(gvgyr bs gur chmmyr).

Comment: Three across is probably "Archie", from the Archie and Jughead comic books.

Comment: And 7D is "slang", because 13A is "magus" (singular of "magi"). I don't have any idea about 20D.

Comment: @PeterShor Ah, of course - nicely spotted on all three counts!

Comment: I meant sinuses and solicitors.

Comment: I think I may understand another aspect of 20D. The answer to 20D is "V", which is the Roman number five. Quadrupled upward, this becomes 20, which is half of 2020. But this doesn't explain the L in Ljubljana.

Comment: @PeterShor, that was not my intention for 20D. (Nice finds for the others.)

Comment: I just realized "Love-ins A" is an anagram for "Slovenia". But I don't understand how that gives you an L in 20D, either.

Comment: No further ideas re 20 Down?

Comment: @msh210 Nope, nothing.

Comment: I think, in 20D clue, specifically "Within half of A.D. 2020", it might hint rot13(jvguva gur 20 Npebff naq 20 Qbja), which then translates to rot13(vafregvat fbzrguvat orgjrra PB naq VQ, juvpu vf bs pbhefr gur yrggre I gb nafjre PBIVQ). Now the trick is... rot13(Vs lbh jevgr I qvntbanyyl, gura vg jvyy orpbzr Y va gur abezny obneq!) Thus, completing the final answer.

Comment: Interesting, @athin, but not my intention.

Comment: I think the best way to find 20D is to work backward from what you already know the answer must sort-of be, bearing in mind how the rest of the puzzle works.

Comment: I should also note that the aforementioned CO_ID is an rot13(hasbeghangr pbvapvqrapr).

Comment: Maybe 20D is ZM - the Nasdaq ticker for Zoom, placed in the centre - the intersection of two black squares - so white? Its stock price went from 68 to 250 during Jan to Jun.  Country code Zambia gives L for the capital.

Comment: @Tom bravo!  That was my intention (except for the explanation of why the square is black. That was just to make it trickier and because a single white square disconnected from all the others looks terrible in a crossword. Too tricky, I think, and for no very good reason, and I probably shouldn't have done it).